# Why does NPM fail installing bcrypt

Tags: node.js

I want to use bcrypt for salts and hashing when I use NPM to try to install I get the following error.

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack error spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack   at errnoException <child_process.js:1001:11>
gyp ERR! stack   at process.childProcess._handle.oneexit<child_process.js.792:34>

gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\program files\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-        gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\jfdfdf\desktop\tntw_wip\API\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v 0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

gyp ERR! bcrypt 0.8.0.33
gyp ERR! Exit status 1
gyp ERR!
gyp ERR! Failed at the bcrypt install
gyp ERR! this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package
gyp ERR! not with npm itself
gyp ERR! tell the author that this fails on your system
gyp ERR!    node-gyp rebuild
gyp ERR! you can get their info via;
gyp ERR!   npm owner is bcrypt
gyp ERR! there is likely additional loggin info above
gyp ERR! system Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program files\\node.js\\\\node.exe" "C:\\program files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bcrypt"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\users\jfdfdf\Desktop\tntw_wip\API
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
gyp ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

I have python installed, gyp installed, current version of node and npm, open ssl, C++, and the SDK needed. I am drilling into the API folder of the project and using shift right click to open my command window to do all of my installs. the environment I am using is windows 7 professional and I am working in brackets.

I have searched and followed several solutions on this issue on both stack and the bcrypt page itself, nothing works. I am new to node other than using NPM to install stuff, so any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're installing `bcrypt`locally and then simply uploading your entire codebase (including your `node_modules` folder) then it's likely a mis-match between the OS and your version of `gyp` and/or `bcrypt`.

If you're not already doing so, try excluding any node modules from your repo and running `npm install` on the server for each deployment, which should automatically pull the correct dependencies depending on the host OS.