# npm install fails on ubuntu 18.04 with error : "Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.3 install script"

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, npm-install, bcrypt, ubuntu-18.04

I get below error while setting up a nodejs project on Ubuntu 18.04. The npm version installed is 6.x and the node version installed is 10.x.

I searched for the fixes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320201/error-installing-bcrypt-with-npm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205121/why-does-npm-fail-installing-bcrypt) on SO but did not get any appropriate fix.

```
    bcrypt@3.0.3 install /home/ubuntu/reko_dev/web/backend/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.3-node-v64-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.3 and node@10.15.0 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-1021-aws
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/ubuntu/reko_dev/web/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/home/ubuntu/reko_dev/web/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/reko_dev/web/backend/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/ubuntu/reko_dev/web/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/home/ubuntu/reko_dev/web/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/reko_dev/web/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-1021-aws
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/reko_dev/web/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/reko_dev/web/backend/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/ubuntu/reko_dev/web/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/home/ubuntu/reko_dev/web/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
npm WARN mongoose-auto-increment@5.0.1 requires a peer of mongoose@^4.1.12 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN rekogapiserver@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2019-01-08T17_09_19_086Z-debug.log
```

Comment: `Error: not found: make` Have you tried to install make?

Comment: This error appears due to `node-pre-gyp`. You need to install some binaries needed by it. Install `node-pre-gyp` and probably you will have to install python, ruby and make.

Comment: @tkausl didnt work.

Comment: @jprivillaso i installed node-pre-gyp and python n ruby. it didnt work ut

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @tkausl mentioned, looks like `make` isn’t installed.

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```